# Spring validation stop on first error and display the error

Tags: spring, validation, spring-validator

I'm using spring validation (@Validated), how do i stop the validation further so that as soon as the first validation fails, return the error response

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    public ResponseEntity<?> Test(@RequestBody @Validated final TestPojo testPojo){

    }
}
```

Validation:

```
public class TestValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz != null && TestPojo.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        if (!(target instanceof TestPojo)) {
            errors.reject("validation.invalid.type");
        } else {
            rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "fname", "validation.field.required");
            rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "lname", "validation.field.required");
            rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "email", "validation.field.required");
        }
    }
}
```

Output response:

```
Errors:
fname is required
lname is required
email is required
```

showing all the errors is not a good idea to client, so how do i stop validation further, if fname validation fails.

Comment: why can't you show just first error?

Comment: but by default all the errors are thrown...
by using **BindingResult** i was able to throw the first error to the client, which ever matches..
`throw bindingResult.getAllErrors().stream().filter(notNull()).findFirst().get();`

Comment: some times objectError.getDefaultMessage() is null, how do i get proper error response from BindingResult ?